# Every element in ArrayList is last element added?

Tags: java

I've got a list of `Places`. Each `Place` has a ArrayList of other `Place's` which are linked to it.

When a `Place` is created it stores an ArrayList of `places`. This ArrayList is generated like so...

```
 public ArrayList<Place> getPlaces(){
`  for(Place p : link.getPlaces()){
      places.add(new Place("Value1","Value2");
   }
   return places;
 }
```

However, the value in `places` seems to always be the last element created. I've checked the constructor of `place` and the places that are being created are different however the value which I receive back in the ArrayList is not. Why would this be happening?

If It helps I'm calling this code from another class which prints the places with something like this...

```
ArrayList<Place> places = p.getPlaces(); //Where p is a place.
for(Place p : places){
   System.out.println(p.toString());
}
```

Comment: Please show a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem. For example, in your first snippet of code, where is `places` declared?

Comment: This code doesn't compile.  Also, you're not creating a new `ArrayList` each time you call `getPlaces()`.  Please post code that actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Btw, it's considered good form to use `List` instead of `ArrayList` unless you specifically need to use the features of the particular implementation.  You say `List<Place> places = new ArrayList<Place>();`

Answer (score 0):

In the first method, all the Place objects will look the same even thought they are different objects.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue myself. Turns out I was soft copying part of my custom object while hard copying the rest which lead me to believe the ArrayList was being overwritten.